# HTTPS/SSL: Apple rules

Tags: ios, ssl, https

My iOS app uses a server side service to chat, upload photo, etc. In order to don't have my script "hacked" and keep my header private, i decided to use SSL encryption provided by a certificat on my Apache server which will handle the resquest and give the response by JSON using PHP/MySQL.

But i heard that Apple doesn't allow HTTPS connection on Apple store, is that true ?
i also heard that i need a US gov certificate, is that true ? even if i am not a US resident ? (I'm european).
Even for just SSL which is known ? i don't use sofisticate self coded algorithm !

If someone had that issue that will help me a lot !
Thanks !

Comment: SSL encryption is not provided by a certificate. The certificate is there for authentication. SSL certificates are not issued by the US Government, they are issued by certificate authorities, and there is one near you. Get one.

Answer (score 0):

No on all counts. I've built and submitted many apps for sale in the US and internationally using self-signed certs on my server with not a peep from Apple.

Comment: It's legal. There is a risk that the clients won't agree to trust the self-signed certificate, in which case no SSL connection will be created.

Comment: i planned to take a certified certificate